# How to connect bluetooth headphones to phone without know the model

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-pairing

I have old bluetooth headphones that I try to connect to my device. I don't know the model only the brand name.

The question is how to pair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for insturction for the brand name. Usually the insturction is the same for all models.

Example for my original question about plantronics:

[pairing-instructions-for-all-plantronics-bluetooth-models](https://www.lexair.com/blog/pairing-instructions-for-all-plantronics-bluetooth-models/)